# Is the Magic Initiate tag too specific?

Tags: discussion, tags

On this question ([Can Players Teach Each Other The Magic Initiate Feat Or Other Feats?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129985/can-players-teach-each-other-the-magic-initiate-feat-or-other-feats)) the tag [magic-initiate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-initiate) has been created, referring to the Magic Initiate feat from D&D 5e.

Does this tag seem too specific to deserve existing? Could we potentially end up having a tag per feat, or even a tag per equivalent-of-a-feat for every system? Or am I being a bit too dramatic here?

Comment: Related to tagging individual feats is [Should we be tagging individual spells?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7520/1204) (current stance is no)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's too specific, it will be eliminated after a period if it's the only instance of the tag.

Don't fret too much over tags.  It's an emergent folksonomy, deliberately.  There are many tags not used much.  We only should be bothering to take action on tags if they are actually causing an issue. "It's not used much" or "it's too specific" is not a real issue.

Answer (score 9):

## It seems too specific

The [help page about tagging](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) says this:

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.
>
> [...]
>
> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

The [magic-initiate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-initiate) tag is too narrow. In particular, the Magic Initiate feat is not even the focus of that question (it's just one example of a feat), so it seems far too specific to be necessary in that case.

I suppose the Magic Initiate feat might be something one could be an expert on, but that particular question is not a good argument in favor of keeping it. The larger issue is that, as you point out, it'd be a system-specific tag for a specific feat; using the same logic, we could create individual tags for every feat/feature in every system that has more than a few questions about it, and that's clearly not the ideal goal.

Comment: On the other hand, [there are 51 questions that specifically mention Magic Initiate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22magic+initiate%22+is%3Aquestion)... I'm beginning to doubt my position. But I'll leave this answer up for those who agree with its perspective.

Comment: I'm curious - why did you remove the tag from the question so soon after posting this to meta? Surely it would have been better to wait a while to gather opinions before you do anything?

Comment: @Wibbs I would have removed the tag as well.  The tag can be added to questions it describes if it's a fine tag (it is), but it definitely doesn't apply to the question it was created on, regardless of this meta.  The not applying is more cut-and-dried I think.

Comment: Ah, fair enough

Comment: Yeah, precisely. Whether or not it should be a tag, it definitely doesn't belong on that question.

Answer (score 1):

## It's not too specific

"Too Specific" isn't an actual problem with tags.  Extremely specific tags are totally fine, provided we have the question activity that leads to their generation.

## It doesn't describe that question

That tag has nothing to do with that question, so it's been removed.  Unless it's used on several questions before the next clean up phase, it will be deleted automatically.