# Tags for basic moves in Dungeon World

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just created a [hack-and-slash](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hack-and-slash) tag and added it to a bunch of questions. I know generally we don't create tags for specific spells, class features etc, but in this case I feel it is warranted. Hack and Slash is one of the basic moves available to all player characters, and there are a lot of questions on the site relating to it.

Before I continue adding the tag to questions, and possibly create tags for some of the other basic moves though, I thought I should double check whether it is necessary....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be fine. We have:

- tags for actions in D&D: [readied-action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readied-action), [opportunity-actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opportunity-actions), [touch-attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touch-attacks), [sneak-attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sneak-attack), [skill-challenge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skill-challenge), to name only a few
- tags for concepts and actions in Fate: [create-advantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/create-advantage), [overcome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overcome), [attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack), [defense](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense) (the latter 2 being used for a number of things as well)
- tags for basic game concepts: [inspiration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration), [advantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage), [rituals](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rituals), [fate-points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-points), [invokes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invokes), [free-invocations](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-invocations), [compels](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compels)

If Hack & Slash is a move a lot of people have been asking about in Dungeon World, then it's good to have a tag to bring those things together and make those questions more discoverable.

If we said Dungeon World *can't* have a tag describing one of its actions that get asked about frequently, I'd instead be quite concerned at the situation Dungeon World questions on this site would be getting put in, given all the other tags I just listed.

People have been citing [Is the Magic Initiate tag too specific?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8275/1204) and [Should we be tagging individual spells?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7520/1204) a lot in the past couple of days so I'm going to pre-empt that here: the reason we don't tag magic spells is because there's like ten thousand of them *at least* across D&D's history, and that would cause some problems we described in that meta. Feats look like they're in a similar position. Dungeon World moves aren't even on a comparable scale; they're someone's marble collection compared to all the grains of sand on a beach.

Comment: It's also true that all DW characters can use all of the basic moves. I suspect it would end up being too much to tag eg. Cleric's advanced move Divine Protection.