# Should we burninate the [shape-water] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Recently, there were several questions posted in quick succession regarding the *shape water* spell in 5e. Shortly after that, a new tag was created for the spell - [shape-water](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shape-water) - and added to the questions. Subsequently, the tag was added to older questions as well.

Given the previous [meta on tagging individual spells](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/should-we-be-tagging-individual-spells) and the decision NOT to do it, should we burninate?

Or is there a good reason that this spell is different and needs it?

Comment: *I love the smell of burnination in the morning ... it smells like ... Victory!*

Comment: Just as a note: this is status-completed in the sense that action was taken (synonymizing), not that burnination was burninated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Tag isn't necessary, but don't need to burninate at this point.

There is nothing special about *shape water* which merits one, so we shouldn't have one for the reasons already given in that meta.

However, we can save our precious diamond mods the effort and just make it a synonym. This is already done for [tensers-floating-disk](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensers-floating-disk) and [tiny-hut](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiny-hut) so we can just do it with this one too.

Comment: The only thing is that it needs people with answer scores of 5+ *in the tag* [tag:shape-water] to suggest and vote for the synonym. I'd suggest, rather, just removing the tag from these couple questions and letting the various cleanup processes deal with the tag.

Comment: @nitsua60 Really? I thought the score requirement applies to the mother tag, ie. [spells].

Comment: Oh, I wonder--I might be reading that wrong. Only one way to find out. To *science*!

Comment: Hope I didn't mess up your science, but I was certainly able to suggest [shape-water] as a synonym of [spells]. (It's [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/spells/synonyms))

Comment: No, I think that sciences it =)

Comment: For the record: the tag synonym has now been approved.

Comment: Got a header/question title mismatch I think.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov sorta. It doesn't need a tag, but it can be synonymed and not burninated.

Comment: @NautArch Ambiguous header is ambiguous.